# Using QLineEdit for passwords

Tags: c++, qt, passwords, qlineedit

How can I make a `QLineEdit` suitable for entering passwords (i.e. it doesn't show what's entered), something like the follwing:

[image]

Answer (score 85):

`setEchoMode` ([Documentation)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#echoMode-prop) for your object.

Example code:

```
ui->lineEditPassword->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
```

You can do it from Qt Designer:

[image]